# Как внедрить в приложение функционал, позволяющий брать определенный текст из html кода в рамках одного сайта

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день! Заранее прошу простить за возможно некорректную постановку вопроса, я еще неопытный андроид разработчик. Проблема такая, требуется создать приложение в котором будет возможность брать определенный текст из HTML кода страниц. Например,существует новостной сайт, на котором есть несколько статьей. Программа должна брать текст из новостных статьей и периодически обновлять его по мере публикации новых.Подскажите пожалуйста, какие средства можно использовать, чтобы реализовать это.

Comment: пожалуйста, попытайтесь как-то конкретизировать ваш вопрос, что за сайт у вас требуется, есть ли у него API какой, на каком этапе у вас возникли трудности и т.д.

Comment: С помощью сайта Яндекс новостей goo.gl/tZM7yo. Api отсутствует.Трудности возникли на этапе проектирования.

Comment: Используй jsoup

Comment: Спасибо большое.